# Techniques in making site easily copyable to MS Word

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

This is kind of an odd question and I didnt know where to post it, but here it is.

I have an ASP .Net website used by internal company employees. The site pages are pretty basic and has various tables, divs, css and some sprinkles of javascript/jQuery.

Some of the site pages are often used for presentations. And sometimes, the users need to copy the content offline.

I got a request that when trying to copy certain pages off IE/Firefox and onto Word/PowerPoint, it does not carry the layout over correctly. Well, I know obviously why this is a problem but the users dont and are asking to make it possible.

I'm assuming that the easiest way to do this is have a "printable" view. But as some of these pages are still being developed, are there some techniques we could follow that would make these pages somewhat copyable to word/ppt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are online guides to doing this [like this one.](http://www.troublefixers.com/word-2010-how-to-paste-html-or-formatted-text-correctly-in-ms-word/)